# xcode 10.1 Cannot find Build Phases Tab

Tags: ios, xcode

I currently use xCode 10.1. Does anyone know how to access the build phases tab? All I can see is Info and Build Settings. I need to find a way to link RCTFBLogin.xcodeproj.

Below is the screenshot:
[image]

Answer (score 5):

You need to open the side panel of the main view by clicking the icon in the upper left corner of it. In the side panel that appears, select your target.

[image: Side panel icon]
[image]